# How to apply function across each row and one of the parameters passed in is a table

Tags: vectorization, apply, kdb

I want to create a column that checks to see that each row of a table can be found in another table using 3 column ids. `x, y and z` are the columns of the table and `transferrable` is the second table

I tried this:

```
elligibleCrossMarginTransfers:{[x;y;z;transferrable]
    potentialTransfers: select from transferrable where marginPctPost>collateralUpperLimitPct,not crossMargin;
    if[1<count select from potentialTransfers where client=x, primeBroker=y,parentPortfolioId=z;
      :1b]; //determine if parentPortfolio of crossMargin exists as possible transfer from other non-cross Margin counts
    :0b
    };
crossMarginNegExcess:update elligibleToTransfer:elligibleCrossMarginTransfers'[client;primeBroker;parentPortfolioId;transferrable] from crossMarginNegExcess
```

Comment: Please supply an example with data - your data structure seems strange (based on what you wrote above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
q)0N!t:flip `a`b`c!(`a`b`c;1 2 3;10 20 30)
+`a`b`c!(`a`b`c;1 2 3;10 20 30)
a b c
------
a 1 10
b 2 20
c 3 30
q)0N!t2:flip `a`b`c!(`a`B`c;1 -2 3;10 -20 30)
+`a`b`c!(`a`B`c;1 -2 3;10 -20 30)
a b  c
--------
a 1  10
B -2 -20
c 3  30
q)t[`elligibleToTransfer]:(`a`b#t) in `a`b#t2
q)t
a b c  elligibleToTransfer
--------------------------
a 1 10 1
b 2 20 0
c 3 30 1
q)
```

updating with two examples you can attempt on your data (provide some samples for more complete answer)

```
crossMarginNegExcess[`elligibleToTransfer]:(`client`primeBroker`parentPortfolioId#crossMarginNegExcess) in select client,primeBroker,parentPortfolioId from transferrable where marginPctPost>collateralUpperLimitPct,not crossMargin
//all qsql
update elligibleToTransfer:1b from `crossMarginNegExcess where ([]client;primeBroker;parentPortfolioId) in select client,primeBroker,parentPortfolioId from transferrable where marginPctPost>collateralUpperLimitPct,not crossMargin
```

Comment: I think this would work if (s)he didn't have the additional logic of filtering the "transferrable" input table. So it may not be a pure key-match

Comment: can he not just do the filtering on the t2 before the #
```t[`elligibleToTransfer]:(`a`b#t) in `a`b#select from t2 where marginPctPost>collateralUpperLimitPct,not crossMargin```

Comment: Yes, that would work assuming the data is set up like that. The original post suggests a different table structure but I realise now that it was likely due to a badly formed query in the OP